# Creating interaction dummy variables for lpSolve constraint

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, lpsolve

I have a linear programming model I'm trying to optimize, and need some help setting up the constraints to get what I want. High-level: I want to choose items only if their "type" doesn't "conflict" with another item's specific "type". Explaining in more depth via example:

1. Select a total of 6 items, maximizing value and keeping the cost under 17k.
2. Each item has 3 "types". They are either labeled `type1` = X or Y, `type2` and `type3` = A, B, or C. For the purpose of this example I've labeled `type2` = A2, B2, C2 and `type3` = A3, B3, C3.
3. 4 items must be type X, 2 must be type Y.

The specific constraint I'm trying to setup is that whatever `Type3`s the chosen 'Y' variables end up being ('A3', 'B3', 'C3'), the `Type2`s of the 'X' variables cannot match that letter. E.g. if the Y's are 'B3', then the X's can either be 'A2' or 'C2'. If one Y is 'C3' and the other is 'A3', then all X's must be 'B2'. Two examples of acceptable solutions:

```
   id type1   type2 type3 value cost 
 3  3     Y     C2    A3   28   240
10 10     X     B2    C3   30   327
11 11     Y     A2    C3   28   350
18 18     X     B2    C3   29   372
40 40     X     B2    B3   29   338
45 45     X     B2    A3   29   277

   id type1   type2 type3 value cost 
 3  3     Y     C2    C3   28   240
10 10     X     B2    C3   30   327
11 11     Y     A2    C3   28   350
18 18     X     B2    C3   29   372
40 40     X     B2    B3   29   338
45 45     X     A2    A3   29   277
```

**My current code only works when both Y's are different `type3`.** To do this I added an interaction vector, Y_3X_2, where if the `type3` matches Y then it gets a value of 10000, and if the `type2` matches X then it gets a value of 1. Each vector is constrained to be <= 100000, so only one of these Y's can be chosen or multiple X's. **I'm looking for help on allowing both of the Y's to be the same `type3`.**

**Working Example**

```
library(dplyr)
library(lpSolve)

id <- 1:50
value <- round(runif(length(id), 10, 30),0)
cost <- round(runif(length(id), 200, 400),0)
type1 <- sample(c(rep('X', 3), 'Y'), length(id), replace = T)
type2 <- sample(c('A2', 'B2', 'C2'), length(id), replace = T)
type3 <- sample(c('A3', 'B3', 'C3'), length(id), replace = T)

df <- data.frame(id, value, cost, type1, type2, type3) %>% 
  mutate(selected = 1)

# Attach dummy vars
type1Dummy <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(df$id, df$type1))
type2Dummy <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(df$id, df$type2))
type3Dummy <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(df$id, df$type3))
df <- cbind(df, type1Dummy, type2Dummy, type3Dummy) 

# Interaction dummy vars
YA3XA2 <- ifelse(df$Y + df$A3 == 2, 10000,
                 ifelse(df$X + df$A2 == 2, 1,
                        0))
YB3XB2 <- ifelse(df$Y + df$B3 == 2, 10000,
                 ifelse(df$X + df$B2 == 2, 1,
                        0))
YC3XC2 <- ifelse(df$Y + df$C3 == 2, 10000,
                 ifelse(df$X + df$C2 == 2, 1,
                        0))

df <- cbind(df, YA3XA2, YB3XB2, YC3XC2)

# constraints
totalNum <- 6
totalCost <- 17000
totalX <- 4
totalY <- 2
intConXYA <- 10000
intConXYB <- 10000
intConXYC <- 10000
rhs <- c(totalNum, totalCost, totalX, totalY, intConXYA, intConXYB, intConXYC)

# Direction vector
numDir <- '=='
costDir <- '<='
xDir <- '=='
yDir <- '=='
intConA <- '<='
intConB <- '<='
intConC <- '<='
dir <- c(numDir, costDir, xDir, yDir, intConA, intConB, intConC)

# Setup opt
obj <- df$value
mat <- t(data.frame(df$selected, df$cost, df$X, df$Y, df$YA3XA2, df$YB3XB2, df$YC3XC2))


# Solver Setup
sol <- lpSolve::lp("max",   
                   objective.in = obj,
                   const.mat    = mat,
                   const.dir    = dir,
                   const.rhs    = rhs,
                   all.bin      = T
)

df$solver <- sol$solution
dfSolved <- df[df$solver == 1,]
dfSolved
```

Walkthrough of code:

- Create dataframe with ID, value, cost, type1/2/3
- Create the dummy variables. These are necessary to tell the optimizer
  to only choose 4 X's and 2 Y's, as well as to setup an interaction
  dummy variable.
- Type1Dummy will create 2 columns. Df$X == 1 if Type1 == 'X', df$Y == 1 if Type2 == 'Y'.
- Type2Dummy will create 3 columns. Df$A2 == 1 if type2 == 'A2', etc
- Type3Dummy will create 3 columns similar to Type2Dummy
- With the dummy variables in place. Create 3 interaction dummy
  variables, YA3XA2 essentially reads as: if type1 == 'Y' & type3 ==
  'A3' |  type1 == 'X' & type2 == 'A2' THEN assign value, else 0. The
  values that are to be assigned are 10000 if type1 == 'Y' and 1 if
  type1 == 'X'.
- Assign right-hand-constraints. Notice the constraints for the
  interaction dummies are 10000. This means that EITHER 1 Y can be
  chosen for that specific type3 or any number of X's can be chosen for
  that specific Y2, but they can never both be selected. If that Y is
  selected then the sum is 10000, and nothing else can be selected.
- **My problem is** that the above constraint is working "too correctly". It successful prevents Y's of certain type3 to be with
  X's of certain type2, but it also means that I can't have 2 Y's of
  the same type3. If I raise the constraint to 20000 then it allows for
  2 Y's of the same type3, but it also allows 1 Y of type3 and 4 X's of
  that type2 (sum = 10004 which is < 20000).

Comment: `df$Y` & `df$A3` are dummy variables, where if `type1` == 'Y' then `df$Y` is 1, and if `type3` == 'A3' then `df$A3` is 1. That's why `YA3XA2` is an "interaction dummy var" because it uses two other dummy vars to get its value. Did you try running my example? I ask because you'd see that it clearly doesn't fail and it's not a problem with R- the example works exactly as it should, I just want it more flexible. And sorry for the convoluted question, I spent over an hour writing and trimming this question down and I don't know how to make it any more concise without removing important details.

Comment: I've deleted my comments and retracted my closevote despite still thinking it is unclear, but perhaps I'm just obtuse. Maybe someone else will be able to "see the light."Generally "interaction dummy variables" are not needed in R. There is an `interaction` function that creates a single vector with alternative levels based on the Cartesian product of levels from the input.

Comment: @42- Hello, I really appreciate that. Honestly this post was sort of a shot in the dark, since I know the constraint I'm looking for is very specific and requires too much detail to explain. I've included somewhat of a walkthrough of my example to try to help guide what I've done so far and what it is that I'm looking for. I hope my first response didn't come off aggressive, I've been working on this thing for weeks and I do appreciate the help!

Comment: I tried solving your problem myself and posting an answer, but it seems I'm not experienced enough to solve the problem in reasonable time. However, I think the key to a solution is to implement a dummy variable that represents the interaction of `x` and `y`; that is the product of binary variables `x_A` times `y_A` and so on. See for example here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860816/linear-programming-with-a-product-term-in-the-objective-function) on how to implement product terms in linear programs.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for giving me that link and for trying to solve it! I know it can be done with `lpSolveAPI` but I just don't think `lpSolve` is flexible enough to do products of binary variables. The tradeoff is that `lpSolveAPI` is much much slower when running hundreds of optimizations.